# AWS SSO change identity source

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, aws-sso, aws-iam-identity-center

When I try to switch the  identity source in IAM identity center(AWS SSO), I'm getting "IAM identity center will delete your current MFA configuration". Does this mean IAM users will also be affected?

I'm expecting the users in IAM not be affected. I expect only resources in IAM identity center to be affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, changing the identity source in AWS Identity Center doesn't affect IAM users in the account. They are different things.